# Next.JS Hot Reload SSR

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

I'm doing development on Next.JS, and every time I hot reload after making a modification of the codes, there seems to be some kind of a cache that causes Client side codes and Server side codes to be different.

Currently, I need to open a new window every time I save my codes, in order to see the updates.

**Is there anything I can do so it auto reload to the latest codes available all the time?**

I tried using helmet/nocache with no results.

```
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')
//const routes = require('./routes')

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
const nocache = require('nocache') //added no cache 

app.prepare()
.then(() => {
  const server = express()
server.use(nocache()) //using no cache

server.get('/listing/:id', (req, res) => {
  const actualPage = '/listing'
  const queryParams = { id: req.params.id }
  return app.render(req, res, actualPage, queryParams)

})


  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(3000, '127.0.0.2', (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000')
  })
})
.catch((ex) => {
  console.error(ex.stack)
  process.exit(1)
})
```

Comment: `every time I hot reload after making a modification of the codes` do you mean client code or server code?

Comment: client codes. in my components. not server.js

Comment: [disabling browser cache](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ywumthjjh5nvysw/Screenshot%202018-10-12%2014.37.41.png?dl=0) might help you

Comment: already installed no cache

Comment: what are you using in **package.json** for **dev** in **scripts**?

Comment: can you snap us the development command? also your next.config.js?